# Building website like codecademy

Tags: web, ide

I wanted to build an interactive site where I can use **an online IDE**. Most of programmers saw the *[codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com)*, where people who are interested in programming want to learn the basics of programming. I do not know what technology I should use in order to create site with online IDE, which can show compilation errors. Please, direct me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something I've looked into myself before and I came across [Ace](http://ace.c9.io/). Although I haven't had the chance to play with it myself yet.

In fact, Codeacademy is built on this library (http://ace.c9.io/#nav=production).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer. :)

Answer (score 9):

Free code camp platform is now open source. You can [download it from Github](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp) and start from there to build your own online educational platform. Free code camp shares many similarities with codecademy. It was written in node.js